# Bootstrap vertical carousel Safari and IE compatibility

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel, vertical-scrolling

I'm working on vertical Boostrap carousel. You can see the test version here: http://activist.guedj.tech/studio

It's working well on FireFox and Google Chrome but I have some issues with the transition with IE and Safari ...

The CSS is just an override of the Boostrap CSS.

**Here is the simplified code:**

```css
.carousel.vertical .item {
    -webkit-transition: 0.6s ease-in-out top;
    -moz-transition: 0.6s ease-in-out top;
    -ms-transition: 0.6s ease-in-out top;
    -o-transition: 0.6s ease-in-out top;
    transition: 0.6s ease-in-out top;
}

@media all and (transform-3d), (-webkit-transform-3d) {
    .carousel.vertical .carousel-inner > .item {
        -webkit-transition: 0.6s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: 0.6s ease-in-out top;
        -o-transition: 0.6s ease-in-out top;
        transition: 0.6s ease-in-out;
    }
    .carousel.vertical .carousel-inner > .item.next, .carousel.vertical .carousel-inner > .item.active.right {
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
        -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
        -o-transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
        transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
        top: 0;
    }
    .carousel.vertical .carousel-inner > .item.prev, .carousel.vertical .carousel-inner > .item.active.left {
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
        -moz-transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
        -o-transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
        transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
        top: 0;
    }
    .carousel.vertical .carousel-inner > .item.next.left, .carousel.vertical .carousel-inner > .item.prev.right, .carousel.vertical .carousel-inner > .item.active {
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        top: 0;
    }
}

.carousel.vertical .active {
    top: 0;
}

.carousel.vertical .next {
    top: 100%;
}

.carousel.vertical .prev {
    top: -100%;
}

.carousel.vertical .next.left,
.carousel.vertical .prev.right {
    top: 0;
}

.carousel.vertical .active.left {
    top: -100%;
}

.carousel.vertical .active.right {
    top: 100%;
}

.carousel.vertical .item {
    left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide vertical" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x315" alt="Chania">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x315" alt="Chania">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x315" alt="Flower">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x315" alt="Flower">
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Left and right controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Can someone help me ?

Thanks !